# Load different language html Xcode

Tags: html, xcode, ios6

I want to load an html file no my app depending on the device language. I already have the code to load an html file without checking the language but now i want to load a file with the format: filename_[LANGUAGE].html

here is my loadHtml code:

```
self.htmlFile = [_htmlFile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".html" withString:@""];
NSString * htmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_htmlFile ofType:@"html"];
NSString * html         = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will return a two letter code for the currently selected language. "en" for English, "es" for Spanish, "de" for German, etc.

Comment: i've already done that, i want to use that language to load the html.
I manipulated the html filename to remove the .html them add the _language and the re-add th .html and its working but is it the best way?

Comment: So append the  string `language` to the string `filename_` and then the `.html` part